# How to handle "@" in password of java URI?

Tags: java, uri

I have a URL "ssh://root:zstackqwe:!@#@172.16.36.184" which contains "@" and ":" in the password part. I use java.net.URI to wrap the string like:

```
URI u1 = new URI("ssh://root:zstackqwe:!@#@172.16.36.184/");
System.out.println(u1.getAuthority());
System.out.println(u1.getHost());
```

the output is:

```
root:zstackqwe:!@
null
```

The authority part is correct while the host part returns null. How should correctly handle those special chars?

**UPDATE:**

The string "ssh://root:zstackqwe:!@#@172.16.36.184" is a raw string without any encoding, passed from the API to my application. I am unable to use constructors other than UIR(string). So I am looking for a way to handle the raw string making it work with jave.net.URI.

Comment: Maybe escaping the string

Comment: I faced this issue, but I don't remember clearly if this could be the right solution: did you try with `zstackqwe\\:!\\@#`?

Comment: Try: `URI u1 = new URI("ssh://root:zstackqwe:!@\\#@172.16.36.184/");`

Comment: I am unable to use constructors other than UIR(string) because the string is passed by the API.

Comment: If you get it from some API, then you can try to it split it by yourself into the parts and then use some other methods from the answers below.

Comment: Ask the API vendor to fix the URI. It is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: the authhority part is wrong too. the last character of the password is missing.  problem is your URL  lis malformed and the host looks like the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a URI use percent encoding.

```
URI u1 = new URI("ssh://root:zstackqwe%3a!%40%23@172.16.36.184/");
```

Answer (score 0):

So that string comes from someone else:

It's mal-formed. Get them to submit a correctly formed URL instead.